# Python regexp to get substring contains '/\'

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I have string

```
ss='/users/parun/kk/jdk/bin/\x1b[01;31m\x1b[kjava\x1b[m\x1b[k'

How to get output

'/users/parun/kk/jdk/bin' only from the above
```

I tried

```
import re
re.split(r'\/\\')
```

But not working

Comment: `\xb1` is a a single "character" denoted by its ordinal hex number. It is not a literal `\\` followed by some characters.

Comment: it is not fixed actually I want from start to till /jdk/bin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regex search might be the best option here:

```py
ss = '/users/parun/kk/jdk/bin/\x1b[01;31m\x1b[kjava\x1b[m\x1b[k'
path = re.findall(r'^.*/jdk/bin', ss)[0]
print(path)  # /users/parun/kk/jdk/bin
```

Comment: Tim, We have not been told that `’/jdk/bin’` is the tail of substring of interest.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I didn't see any other reliable way of formulating a pattern here.  In any case, the OP has accepted this answer.